# Сортировка по нескольким столбцам (датам) sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, есть 2 вида информирования, звонком и письмом. Нужно их сортировать по убыванию одновременно, то есть, сначала идет 22 марта сот, потом 21 марта письмо, потом опять 20 марта сот и так далее, как это сделать? В данном запросе, как я понимаю, задается первостепенный и второстепенный критерий при совпадении одного из них, но у меня совпадений быть не может, так как человек информирован в этот день либо звонком либо письмом.

```
SELECT sot, pocht
from table
order by sot, pocht desc
```

Comment: какого типа столбцы: sot, pocht ? и приведите пример данных из вашей таблицы

Comment: datetime, 2022-02-25 00:00:00.000

Comment: Покажите пример данных и требуемый результат сортировки.

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду под примером, выше написал значение, которое принимает ячейка, оно также может быть NULL, если значение в другом столбце заполнено. Результат таков: 1) sot:2022-02-25 00:00:00.00, pocht: NULL; 2)  sot:NULL , pocht:2022-02-24 00:00:00.00; 3) 1) sot:2022-02-23 00:00:00.00, pocht: NULL. 1, 2, 3 - строки, значения столбца через двоеточие. То есть сортировка по дате убывания, сразу для двух столбцов, технически такое возможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не уверен, что вы хотите, но может быть это?

```
declare @t table (sot datetime, pocht datetime)
insert into @t (sot, pocht)
values ('20220325', null), (null, '20220320'), ('20220225', null), (null, '20220321'), ('20220321', null)

SELECT coalesce(sot, pocht) as [date], case when sot is null then 'pocht' else 'sot' end as [send by]
from @t
order by [date] desc, [send by] desc
```

вариант для большего кол-ва полей (добавлен столбец sms):

```
declare @t table (sot datetime, pocht datetime, sms datetime)
insert into @t (sot, pocht, sms)
values ('20220325', null, null), (null, '20220320', null), ('20220225', null, null), (null, '20220321', null), ('20220321', null, null), (null, null, '20220328'), (null, null, '20220320')


select t.sot as [date], 'sot' as [send]
from @t t where t.sot is not null
union all
select t.pocht as [date], 'pocht' as [send]
from @t t where t.pocht is not null
union all
select t.sms as [date], 'sms' as [send]
from @t t where t.sms is not null
order by 1 DESC, 2 DESC
```

Comment: Вроде бы то, помечу как ответ, если в процессе будут вопросы - дополню, спасибо большое!

Comment: Еще один маленький вопрос, как взять даты от 2022 года, что нужно прописать в where?

Comment: where coalesce(sot, pocht) >= '20220101'

Comment: А если добавить еще 1 столбец, например 'sms' с теми же условиями и данными, как можно код поменять?

Comment: я бы порекомендовал переделать структуру таблицы . сделать один столбец с датой и другой с типом (1-мобильный, 2 - почта, 3 - смс), тогда всё станет намного проще.

Comment: если структура таблицы останется прежней и будет добавлен новый столбец с датой sms, то делайте выборку с использованием union all

Comment: структура не моя) я добавил несколько when, посмотрел, все работает, больше ничего не менял, насколько это адекватное решение?